# .DS_Store is showing up as a pending change in my Git repo despite being untracked

Tags: git

I'm working out of a remote Github repository that I cloned locally. I started a new project in my local repo with `create-react-app`, which among other things, automatically generates a `.gitignore` file that includes `.DS_Store`. I pushed up the empty project to the remote repo, created a branch locally, and did some initial work in the project. When I wrapped up for the day, I added and committed all of my changes on the branch, but after doing that, my VSCode source control panel still showed me that I had one pending change: in the `.DS_Store` file, even though VSCode explicitly tells me that that file is untracked (when I open the `.DS_Store` file, the tab in VSCode literally says ".DS_Store (Untracked)").

Then, when I run `git status` I get this:

```
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ../.DS_Store

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I tried adding and committing again, but since the file is apparently untracked, the pending change is still there. Merging my branch back in with main and pushing to the remote repo gave me no issues, but VSCode is still telling me that I have that one last pending change. I also don't see the file anywhere in my repository at all from Finder, even though I have hidden files visible. I'm very confused why it's tracking a change in an untracked file. Can anyone help me out with what's going on?

Comment: is .gitignore in the current directory? .gitignore only applies to directory contents and subdirectories. So if your repo root is one level above your gitignore, the DS_Store file from the repo root could be included.

Answer (score 2):

git is tracking changes to `.DS_Store` because it was added to your repo via `git add` or some variation of `git add`. You may have even added other files in your working folder and its subfolders, inadvertently adding unrelated files that you couldn't even see. Nevertheless, git is now tracking changes on everything you told it to track with `git add`, intentionally or not.

To make git ignore them once and for all...
**1) add them** to `.gitignore`; and then
**2) `git rm`** them from git's repo as follows:

*1) Add the filenames to `.gitignore`*

As mentioned elsewhere in this thread, you should have just one `.gitignore` file and that file should reside at the top ("root") directory folder of your repo.

`cd` to that directory and append the names and locations of the unwanted files to your `.gitignore` using this `zsh` *(or syntax-adjusted `bash`-equivalent)* loop:

```
for f in `/bin/ls -R ./**/.DS_Store`; do echo $f; done >> ./.gitignore
```

Then...

*2) Delete your repo's references to those files*

**Remove** the output append redirect (`>> ./.gitignore`) from the end of the loop and use the rest to remove git's references to the files...

```
for f in `/bin/ls -R ./**/.DS_Store`; do git rm $f; done
```

For any that git warns you are "changed", run `git rm --cached` against those.

**Notes**

*Note 1*

It's never a bad idea to use git's dry-run feature (`-n`) so you can see how `git` will respond without breaking anything.

For example,

```
git rm -n ./*/**/.DS_Store

git rm -n --cached ./.DS_Store
```

*Note 2*

Be aware that when you're done you will have only removed the files from **git's** purview but **NOT** from your actual file system, which is important since these happen to be hidden files related to MacOS itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your post title reads:

> .DS_Store is showing up as a pending change in my Git repo despite being untracked

You're right that it is untracked:

> ```
> On branch develop
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
>
> Untracked files:
>   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
>         ../.DS_Store
>
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
> ```

But your claim that it is a "pending change [to your] Git repo", from the title, is wrong.  (It's possible that VSCode, which does its own thing, is misleading you here, since you mentioned VSCode, but you've posted this with [git](/questions/tagged/git) and not [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code)—edit: oh, I see someone *removed* that tag).  It's merely showing up as an untracked file.  *This is normal!*  You just want to get Git to shut up about it, using `.gitignore`.<sup>1</sup>

As [Michael Delgado said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69005605/ds-store-is-showing-up-as-a-pending-change-in-my-git-repo-despite-being-untrack#comment121957851_69005605), the path name:

```
../.DS_Store
```

is significant here.  This means that you are in a subdirectory of your working tree: some folder *within* the working tree, not at the top level where the `.git` directory itself exists.  You'll need to ascend one level:

```
cd ..
```

before creating or updating the `.gitignore` file that should list the `.DS_Store` file that the Mac Finder creates.  If you are in, say, `app/` within the top level, the file `app/.gitignore` cannot make Git ignore (shut up about) the file `.DS_Store` in the top level.  It *can* ignore the file `app/.DS_Store`, but not the top-level one.

---

<sup>1</sup>It *is* a good idea to get Git to shut up about it.  Ideally, every output line from `git status` should be useful.  The fact that `.DS_Store` is not going to be committed is desirable, so complaining about it, as Git is doing, is *not* useful.

Answer (score -1):

If the gitignore rule is created after git areadly logged the .DS file it will be carried in the update.

Comment: yeah but the file wouldn't show up as untracked

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that - but .DS_Store was automatically included in .gitignore when the project was created, and I can't seem to actually see the file anywhere either. VSCode itself is also telling me that the file is untracked so I'm confused why it's showing up as a pending change